# LibreOffice Base menu disappears

Tags: unity, libreoffice

I just installed LibreOffice Base on my 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10 machine. It worked great at first, but the menu at the top of the screen will no longer appear at the top. It was working at first. The menu I am talking about is the strip that contains the File, Edit, and other menus.

I restarted my computer, but it didn't work. I reinstalled Base, but that didn't work. Other LibreOffice products and other programs such as Calc or Gedit display the menus normally.

[image: The File, Edit, and other menus will no longer show.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely [bug 1064962](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1064962) (LibreOffice, SRUed and fixed in quantal-proposed) and [bug 1075263](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/1075263) (Indicator-appmenu, should be prepared for SRU soon).

Answer (score 0):

i'd the same problem before,
so the way to solve it is just go to Libreoffice window,and View menu --> Full Screen and your libre workspace will be right on your nose